# Move the row to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet, that I need to move the row, if the value on the last column is equal to false.
I don't know how to move to sheet 2 and make go through entire sheet.
Thank for the help.

```
Sub DeleteMatches2()
    Dim a As Range, b As Range
    Dim c As String
   'The column that has the value is V2
    With Sheets("Controle Estoque Fixo")
        Set a = .Range(.Cells(2, "V"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each b In a
        If b.Value = "False" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            'know I am lost

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: did you search SO? There's a bagazillion examples of how to do this on here. Also, what have you *actually tried* to copy the row to another sheet?

Comment: Quick note, also make sure to add the `.` before `Rows.Count` when you `Set a`.  For the next part, you'll just want to find the next row in your Sheet2 (use a variable), then you can cut/paste.  There are myriad examples of what you're asking for here, so just use the Search box.  I'd suggest using the macro recorder, cut/paste, and see what that code looks like, and tweak from there.

Comment: lol I like how you use `with` then proceed to use `select` XD

Comment: @ScottHoltzman how many is a `bagazillion`?

Comment: @ScottCraner - it's the square-root of googleplex to the 181st power over 91.

Comment: @ScottCraner just use type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, the simplest is to keep a row counter, which tracks how many rows you've used on on the other sheet. Increment this counter by one each time. Lets assume you have column headers on sheet1, so the first available row is row 2:

```
Sub DeleteMatches2()

    Dim a As Range, b As Range
    Dim c As String
    Dim rowCounter As Long

    rowCounter = 2 ' start at row 2

   'The column that has the value is V2
    With Sheets("Controle Estoque Fixo")
        Set a = .Range(.Cells(2, "V"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each b In a
        If b.Value = "False" Then
            'Sheets("Sheet1").Select ' you don't need to select an object to access it, so remove this
            'here's the bit you need
            Sheets("Controle Estoque Fixo").Rows(b.row).Cut Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(rowCounter) ' this cuts and pastes all in one line
            ' you use the row counter to specify the destination

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1 ' the next time you'll paste on the next row

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As people have commented there are many many many ways to do this so have a good look on Stack Overflow, something else might appeal to you.